# How to use default sound driver

Tags: drivers, sound

When I had ubuntu installed, sound was working out of the box. But then I wanted better quality like in windows. So I tried installing drivers from Realtek page but installation failed. Now I have no sound at all. How can I go back and use default driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to settings go to software and updates

go to additional drivers

see if it shows up that way?